# Populate page dynamically with field contents from a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-query-web-part, cswp

I have a Sharepoint list "SiteInfo" which has the following columns:-

- Site Name
- IP Address
- ISP
- Username

I would like to be able to do the following:-

On my main SharePoint site page, I'd like a drop down box that is pre-populated with Site Names from the SiteInfo list.

When you choose a Site Name and click Go/Search (or whatever), this should take you to a new page which is dynamically populated with the IP Address, ISP and Username fields.

I'm guessing I need to use the Content Search or Content Query web parts, but I am struggling to get my head around how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Rest API with data tables(Search included) with chosen JQuery(With the list of Site Name). This will look really good for what you want to accomplish.